# How to restart a docker container from .net core

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I'm running a `BackgroundService` inside a docker container, but sometimes when it starts, a dependancy running on another container might not be ready yet. So I made a `CriticalHostedService` class that crash to restart the docker container when it happens.

```
public abstract class CriticalHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            await ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {                
            FatalExit();
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Make sure the service restart when there is an error
    /// </summary>
    private void FatalExit()
    {
        ((IApplicationLifetime)serviceProvider
            .GetService(typeof(IApplicationLifetime)))
            .StopApplication();
    }
}
```

Now this worked fine with linux container. When FatalExit was called, the container stopped and was restarted from my docker-compose policy `restart: always`.

But with windows containers, the container keeps running and nothing appears in the logs.

How should I restart my windows docker from inside my .net core application?

Comment: You need to specify your executable as entrypoint of container, so when that process dies, your container dies

Comment: @GregorySuvalian I'm using the default config for asp.net-core project. No exe are builded, only a .DLL. This is what's in my dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApi.dll"]`

Comment: You can add `HEALTCHECK` then I guess which will kill container too if not passed.

Comment: Why not simply to use bash and docker command to check for a process in another docker container to complete?